# Hit Testing in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, graphics, hittest

I have an `Ellipse` on a `Canvas` and I'm doing Hit Testing on it.
Every time I click the stroke of the `Ellipse`, the test passes.
If I click in the middle of the `Ellipse`, the test fails.
This is good!

After I fill the ellipse like this: `myEllipse.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);`,
the test pasess also when I click in the middle of the `Ellipse`.

How can I disable this?
(even when `Ellipse` is Filled, the test will fail when I click in the middle)
Thanks !

Answer (score 8):

If you do your own hit testing (see [Hit Testing in the Visual Layer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752097.aspx) for details on how to do this), you should be able to check the [IntersectionDetail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.intersectiondetail.aspx) of the [GeometryHitTestResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.geometryhittestresult.aspx) is **IntersectionDetail.Intersects**, and not **IntersectionDetail.FullyContains**.

Comment: The link to 4.5 does not show(?)...but 4.0 works. [Hit Testing in the Visual Layer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms752097%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Cant you put a smaller ellipse in the middle of it and set IsHitTestVisible="false" ?

Comment: This will not prevent the lower ellipse from getting hit, IsHitTestVisible=false makes that element invisible to hit testing, but it does not affect elements below the affected element.