# MouseDown/Up events not working properly in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, togglebutton

I have a custom control based on ToggleButton. In its constructor, I create a few elements of type `FrameworkElementFactory` and to one of them I assign an EventHandler like this:

button.AddHandler(Ellipse.MouseDownEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(Toggle));

And here's my event handler:

```
private void Toggle(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var active = GetTemplateChild("Active");
    var button = GetTemplateChild("ToggleButton");
    Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();

    var ta = new ThicknessAnimation();
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(ta, new PropertyPath("Margin"));
    Storyboard.SetTarget(ta, button);
    ta.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.2);


    var da = new DoubleAnimation();
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(da, new PropertyPath("Width"));
    Storyboard.SetTarget(da, active);
    da.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.2);

    if ((bool)IsChecked)
    {
        ta.To = new Thickness(0);
        da.To = (double)button.GetValue(Ellipse.WidthProperty);
        IsChecked = !IsChecked;
    }
    else
    {
        ta.To = new Thickness(this.Width - (double)button.GetValue(Ellipse.WidthProperty), 0, 0, 0);
        da.To = this.Width;
        IsChecked = !IsChecked;
    }

    sb.Children.Add(ta);
    sb.Children.Add(da);
    sb.Begin();
}
```

But it doesn't work. Doesn't work in the sense that it works only once. I mean it is supposed to set a slider's width based on the `IsChecked` property. Initially, it is set to `false`. When I click it, it expands to the right as expected. But when I click again, it does not move left as expected.

The more surprising thing is that it works perfectly with the `MouseEnter` event. All other events like `MouseDown/Up/LeftMouseButtonUp/PreviewMouseDown.....` are not working either.

If you want to reproduce the problem without much editing use the code [here](http://pastebin.com/Btd64LUi).
Then just use it in a WPF app and you'll see.

Any help much appreciated.

**Edit:** Another discovery: It works with Right Clicks and Middle Button Clicks but not with Left Clicks. Wonder why...?? **My mouse works fine.**

**Edit#2:** [Converters](http://pastebin.com/P5PRkqmX)

Comment: Out of curiosity, why aren't you using the storyboard and triggers in Xaml?

Comment: Can't use binding with storyboard...some freezable issue. More info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186933/wpf-animation-binding-to-the-to-attribute-of-storyboard-animation)

Comment: Why not use the `Button.Clicked` event?

Comment: @user1 It is an `Ellipse`, not a `Button`. I'm sorry I didn't mention it.

Comment: Good point... your example is set up for mouse enter is that a typo?

Comment: yeah a typo. it should be mouse down. wait, i'll fix it.

Comment: You did not include the converters to the pastebin

Comment: you might want to check if it performs a hit test  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001930/hit-testing-in-wpf

Comment: @JanneMatikainen I have now posted them.

Comment: Any reason you aren't binding the `IsChecked` property to a local control DependencyProperty and simply reacting to the PropertyChangedCallback?  Might be a lot simpler...  Also, make sure nothing else is stealing your mouse focus!

Comment: I understand that this code can be made better and optimized. But if any of those were the case not even the Right Click would have worked, would it?

Comment: Why not use something like this http://marcangers.com/animated-switch-togglebutton-style-in-wpf/ ?

Comment: Did you try button.AddHandler(Ellipse.MouseDownEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(Toggle), true); ?

Comment: @galakt Didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having implemented a couple custom controls I've found some interesting behavior dealing with mouse events in particular.  Basically, you may be running into a case where another control, possibly even in your `ControlTemplate` is stealing the mouse focus and consuming the mouse event before you get it.

There are two solutions to the problem:

- Use [MousePreviewEvents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouse.previewmousedown(v=vs.110).aspx), and be careful not to mark the event consumed
- Bind to the actual property that you are wanting to see changed

In this particular case I would have an `InternalIsCheckedProperty` that you bind to the `ToggleButton.IsCheckedProperty` to invoke your storyboard.

Comment: After seeing your answer, I tried to see if the Event fired at all by using a MessageBox after the storyboard. Quite surprisingly, after I clicked OK, it worked perfectly every time even with the Left Click.

Comment: I ended up using the second option.

Answer (score 8):

`MouseDown` and `MouseUp` events are fired by `UserControl`.
You should use the events: `PreviewMouseDown` and `PreviewMouseUp`.

Further, you may use `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave` events in order to address the visual feedback when the mouse is located over your object.